# Django equivalent of SQL not in

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a very simple query: `select * from tbl1 where title not in('asdasd', 'asdasd')`.

How do I translate that to Django? It's like I want the opposite of: `Table.objects.filter(title__in=myListOfTitles)`

Answer (score 200, accepted):

try using [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

```
Table.objects.exclude(title__in=myListOfTitles)
```

Comment: This does not work with related fields. Negating the is not the same as not in. For example `Publisher.objects.filter(book__author__in=XXX`).

Comment: Maybe you should do it step by step then. Here is a line from an application of mine : `User.objects.exclude(id__in=Group.objects.get(id=kwargs['group_id']).user_ids.all())` which returns all the users that are not in the group which has `group_id` as id.

Comment: be aware, that exclude places "or" between conditions.

Answer (score 40):

(this thread is old but still could be googled)

you can use `models.Q` with "~" as follows:

```
Table.objects.filter(~Q(title__in=myListOfTitles))
```

this method specially is helpful when you have multiple conditions.

Answer (score 29):

```
Table.objects.exclude(title__in=myListOfTitles)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Django provides two options.**

```
exclude(<condition>)
filter(~Q(<condition>))
```

Method 2 using Q() method

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> queryset = User.objects.filter(~Q(id__lt=5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `exclude`:

```py
Table.objects.exclude(title__in=myListOfTitles)
```

You can also combine `filter` and `exclude`

```py
Table.objects.filter(title__in=includingTitles).exclude(title__in=excludingTitles)
```