# Django Not in for Related Fields

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

How would I do a `not in` filter in Django when I have related fields?

```
class Publisher(Model):
  pass

class Author(Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)
  publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
```

I can write:

```
Publisher.objects.filter(author__name__in=XXX)
```

this does not work:

```
Publisher.objects.filter(author__name__not_in=XXX)
```

And while this [Django equivalent of SQL not in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003518/django-equivalent-of-sql-not-in) claims you can use `exclude`, this is not correct:

```
Publisher.objects.exclude(author__name__in=XXX)
```

`XXX` is a list of names.

To clarify what I want to get:  I would like to find all publishers that have an author NOT in that list. Note: these publishers may also have an author IN that list.

Let's say I have two publishers A, B and the following Authors for the publishers:

```
A: Alex, Bob, Greg
B: Alex, Greg
```

xxx is ['Alex', 'Greg']

I would like to find any Publisher that has an Author not in that list. In this case A should be returned since A has author Bob which is not in that list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) would be a good fit for this query.

You can build up the query params first.

```
import operator

query = reduce(
    lambda x, y: operator.or_(Q(author__name=x), Q(author__name=y)),
    XXX
)
# query would be something like Q(author__name='Alex') | Q(author__name='Greg')

Publisher.objects.exclude(query)
```

Example using exact matches, if you're looking to search **in** a CharField you have to use [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or `icontains`. Just update Q object with `Q(author__name__icontains=n)`.

Comment: If xxx is the variable's name containing a string, then, `''` are not needed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Wasn't clear what XXX was before last update in the question, so I tried to make it clear by saying it had to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) function. It's the inverse of the `filter()` function, but does exactly what you're looking for.

Note that you can also [chain functions together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters):

```
>>> Entry.objects.filter(
...     headline__startswith='What'
... ).exclude(
...     pub_date__gte=datetime.date.today()
... ).filter(
...     pub_date__gte=datetime(2005, 1, 30)
... )
```

Comment: I'm a pretty sure I do NOT want the inverse of filter in this case. I would like to find all publishers that have an author NOT in that list. Note: these publishers may also have an Author IN that list.

Answer (score 0):

What is `XXX`, If it is a `list` you should be able to use `exclude` in your query.

```
Publisher.objects.exclude(author__name__in=XXX)  # Remember XXX must be a list
```

If it is a `string` you should use:

```
Publisher.objects.exclude(author__name__contains=XXX)
```

Or if case does not matter:

```
Publisher.objects.exclude(author__name__icontains=XXX)
```

Comment: Updated to show `XXX` is a list. Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538768/django-not-in-for-related-fields#comment49151097_30538846 exclude is not what I want.

Comment: Please be clear `exclude` does not work, or it is not returning what you expect?

Comment: It is not returning what I want. I do not want to negate the entire filter, I want to negate the in.

Comment: Can you show an example with data, XXX value, and what you expect?

Comment: Updated with richer example.

Comment: I think this is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30539157/3945375). As he said it will take a cost, but is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used:

```
Publisher.author.filter(author__in=Author.objects.exclude(name__in=xxx))
```

There is a performance cost associated with the potentially huge subquery, especially on MySQL which doesn't handle subqueries all that well.

An alternative is to implement a `NOT IN` [custom lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-lookups/), which has been possible since 1.7. It would look something like this:

```
class NotInLookup(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'not_in'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s NOT IN (%s)' % (lhs, rhs), params
```

You'll have to investigate the documentation and possibly the [source code of `IN`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/lookups.py#L262) for the right way to write this lookup. There might be interest to add it to core, so if you get it working, feel free to bring it up on the mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-developers.